# Google map touch events on google chrome and windows8/IE10

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im currently editing a Wordpress theme called explorable (http://elegantthemes.com/preview/Explorable/)

The final site will be hosted on a windows 8 touch screen device and will be an interactive map.

I am having a few problems with the touch screen mechanics and decided to use google chromes built in, Emulate touch events feature. However I can't seem to drag the map at all unless I have the iphone/ipad user agent also ticked.

I checked the documentation and drag is enabled by default so I'm not sure why this is turned off for desktop, this might also be the reason why I cant get drag to work on the windows8 box.

Not sure if Im missing something thing obvious or not, or that I just need to declare a setting when the map is initiated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

This issue was handled in the bug

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35824421

and was solved in version 3.27 of Google Maps JavaScript API in December 2016.

Comment: the example seems to have safari, iPhone and tablet classes in the body. Not sure why this is. Since I'm using chrome on desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Google chrome does not support touch events very well on windows 8 touch devices. However IE10 does so I set the application to run on this browser.

For what i need the application to do this worked well, however this might not be the best solution for other people having trouble with touch actions on chrome in windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact a Google Map bug [#6425](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6425).

Check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661844/touch-events-not-working-with-google-maps-in-angular) for another workaround using User Agent spoofing.