# Google Map pinch not working on Microsoft Surface

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Perform a pinch operation on the [Google Maps Custom Controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom), Pinch does not work.
How can I change the zoom of the map in a pinch?

Example

- https://map-sample-dot-cp300demo1.appspot.com/sample/index.html

Environment

- Chrome version 50.0.2661.102 m
- Microsoft Windows 10 Version 1511(OS Build 10586.318)

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps JavaScript API has been designed to load quickly and work well on mobile devices. Mobile devices have smaller screen sizes than typical browsers on the desktop. As well, they often have particular behavior specific to those devices (such as "pinch-to-zoom"). For more information and sample code visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics).

Try to follow the steps here in this [discussion](http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/357755-pinch-and-zoom-touch-screen-gestures-no-longer-work/) to work the pinch in Microsoft Surface.

Steps we Followed:

1. Launch the Win8.1 VDA on a Surface pro1 / HP Elite Pad in Windowed mode.
2. Open the IE browser within the session and open Google Maps .
3. Try to Pinch / Zoom the google Maps within the desktop session.

Also try to check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661844/touch-events-not-working-with-google-maps-in-angular) for more information.